# Composer exit batch file after finish execution

Tags: php, batch-file, composer-php

I am trying to do some automation with batch file to perform installing of laravel and then continue with moving files & folder.

My batch file looks something like this:

```
@echo off

echo Installing laravel...
composer create-project laravel/laravel system --prefer-dist

echo Laravel installing is done... Now moving files and folder...
......
```

The problem is as soon as the `composer` finish installing laravel, it exit the batch file.

How can I get the process going after the `composer` task is done?

Comment: Why is it this question is down-voted? Please suggest better way of asking while you down vote. TQ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could bet that the installer is a `composer.bat` Batch file! If so, execute it via `call` command:

```
@echo off

echo Installing laravel...
call composer create-project laravel/laravel system --prefer-dist

echo Laravel installing is done... Now moving files and folder...
```

Comment: First of all, the batch file is not called `composer.bat`. However, after adding `call` into it, it is now does not exit batch after executing composer. Thanks a lot for your great help!!!!

Comment: Well, if the problem was solved adding a `call` command, then the only explanation is that the file is called `composer.bat` or `composer.cmd`...

Comment: -_-  Well, I am experiment it on a new empty folder and there is only one batch file in that folder and I am 100% sure that the batch file is not called `composer.bat` or `composer.cmd`.

Comment: This is funny! You had said a couple times that the `composer` file is _not_ called `composer.bat` nor `composer.cmd`, but you had not said **how it is called**!!! So, **what is the extension of the `composer` file???** I would like to know this info in order to understand the operation of Batch files, because if `composer` file have _not_ "bat" nor "cmd" extension, then I don't understand why the inclusion of `call` command solved this problem!!!

Comment: That `composer` is composer-php (https://getcomposer.org/). I don't know how it works and what file name it is using. All I am saying is on my working folder, there is only one batch file and it is not called `composer`.

Comment: Please, copy the next line, paste it at the command prompt and press Enter; then, report the output: `for %a in (composer.bat composer.cmd) do @echo/%~$PATH:a`

Comment: This is the output `~$PATH:a was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Ok, no problem; the answer is [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows): "Create a new composer.bat file alongside composer.phar". The file is called `composer.bat` and it is placed in the directory created by composer installation, that is included in %PATH% variable...